# How can I show a form with the old values so that you can edit?

Tags: forms, symfony

in controller I find the id

```
 $oggetto = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AcmeTryBundle:Try')
        ->find($id);
```

after I passed this $values into form(just?)

```
$form = $this->createForm(new TryType(), $oggetto);
```

and in FormType? what I put?

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name','text')  ?
```

Comment: You mean form where, in case of errors, typed values are remembered? (it: intendi un form dove i valori sono ricordati in caso di errore?)

Comment: sei italiano?
i want show the old value, when update the id
<input type=text value={{ value }}

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is good.

1) Get your `$oggetto` object in DB

2) Pass it to your FormType `$form = $this->createForm(new TryType(), $oggetto);`

3) Add the fields you want in your form type

4) Send your form to your view `'form' => $form->createView()`

5) In your view, call your form

```
<form action="{{ path('task_new') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Your fields (you defined in 3) ) will be automaticaly populated by your object data. You can then change them and edit them.

See the doc for more info: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

Comment: return 
Expected argument of type "scalar", "DateTime" given

Comment: Could you be more explicit on this error, could you edit your question and show us: what's in your FormType and in your Entity? :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Form seems fine

```
class TryFormType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder->add('name','text')  ;
        }

 public function getName() {
        return 'tryform';
    }
}
```

The function getName gives the form a name, which in this case is tryform.

In the controller you can add a return statement like this.

```
return $this->render('AcmeTryBundle:Default:TryForm.html.twig', array(
                    'TryForm' => $form->createView()
                ));
```

And in twig file access it as follows.

```
{{ form_widget(TryForm.name) }}
```

The value will automatically be passed there. You can then edit it

Answer (score 0):

For example in **Symfony 4.2.3**,  you filled and submitted a form and some form values are invalid.

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{ form.vars.value.name }}">
```

In this way, you will be set old form input as a default value if the value is valid.